# Why my automated test case browser will automatically going to closed?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

When I execute my automation test case, after executing the test cases in  the  browser,Browser will automatically  going to closed ?

This is my test case.

```
   *** Settings ***
 Library  SeleniumLibrary     implicit_wait=20  
 Variables   a.py
 Suite Teardown  Close Browser

*** Variables ***
${Site}   https://example.com


*** Test Cases ***
Check Application List
Login
Click Link             /app/home   
Sleep   1                          
Click Link            /app/page1
Wait Until Page Contains       Showing you
Click Link                     Applications1
Wait Until Page Contains       Showing you 
Page Should Contain            Application 
#Set Browser Implicit Wait  


 *** Keywords ***
Login
 Open Browser    ${Site}     Chrome
 Input Text      USER        ${Uname}
 Input Password  PASSWORD    ${Password}
 Click Button    login
```

Comment: Because you have `driver.close()`?

Comment: You must be telling it to close. By default it won't close.

Comment: No, I have not used driver.close() also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifically asking for the browser window to close when the suite has finished running:

```
Suite Teardown   Close Browser
```

Comment: Thank you! , Sorry I am new to Robot Framework testing,  After removing the Keyword It's working now